# error: invalid string constant "murrine-scrollbar", expected valid string constant while running groovy console with Java9

Tags: java, groovy, java-9, groovy-console

I was playing with DMelt 2.1 in http://jwork.org/dmelt/ and I've noticed I cannot start the Groovy console when using JDK9 (On Ubuntu 17.08, x64, JDK build 9.0.1+11). Then I noticed that JDK9 throws a lot of warnings even when using the original "groovyConsole" from the groovy-2.6.0-alpha-2 package from the Apache web site http://groovy-lang.org/:

```
groovy-2.6.0-alpha-2/bin/groovyConsole
WARNING: Using incubator modules: jdk.incubator.httpclient
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedClass (file://Download/groovy-2.6.0-alpha-2/lib/groovy-2.6.0-alpha-2.jar) to method java.lang.Object.finalize()
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedClass
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "overlay-scrollbar"
/usr/share/themes/Ambiance/gtk-2.0/apps/mate-panel.rc:30: error: invalid string constant "murrine-scrollbar", expected valid string constant
```

How can this be fixed? I do not have any issues when using JDK 1.8.

Comment: Additionally, those are just WARNINGs for Java9. Your actual failure in logs may be the [Gtk-Message in there](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntu-themes/+bug/1723422).

Comment: Just to add to it , [Java9 uses GTK+ 2 by default](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/whatsnew/toc.htm#JSNEW-GUID-983469B6-9BB5-48CA-B71D-8D7012B2F3CA) if not available fails forwards to GTK+ 3. *To use a specific version of GTK+, set the system property jdk.gtk.version. This system property may have a value of 2, 2.2, or 3. You must set this property before your application loads GTK+, and it must not conflict with a GTK+ version that may have been loaded earlier by another toolkit.*

Comment: What this behavior is different from JDK8 which does not care about GTK versions?

Comment: The behavior is not different, the failure as linked in the first comment could not possibly be because of Java version. Secondly, the important part here could be that tools used *must set this property before your application loads GTK+, and it must not conflict with a GTK+ version that may have been loaded earlier by another toolkit.*

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this:

```
sudo chown -R username /home/username/.config/octave/
```

Please check this: https://github.com/conda-forge/octave-feedstock/issues/8

Comment: I do not have such directory in Ubuntu 17.08 (unity desktop mode)